# Apache does not start

Tags: linux, web-server, apache2, fedora

I am trying to start Apache on my Webserver but I keep getting this error: httpd.service: Failed with result 'protocol'.

Any solution would be appreciated.

Edit: Log Entries

```
Jun 3@ 63:41:59 racknerd-eaebS1 httpd[147681: AH@8558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain
Jun 3@3:41:59 racknerd-eaeb51 httpd[147681]: httpd (pid 26287) already running
Jun 3@ @3:41:59 racknerd-eaebS1 systemd[1]: httpd.service: Failed with result ‘protocol’.
Jun 3@ 63:41:59 racknerd-eaeb51 systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
-- Subject: Unit httpd.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/ list info/systemd-devel
-- Unit httpd.service has failed
-- The result is failed.
```

Comment: Actual error log entries and your configuration would be helpful.

Comment: Did that, thank you.

Comment: The Apache configuration is missing, and I was talking about the actual error logs of Apache. the systemctl status command is pretty useless.

Comment: Check the second line in the log

Answer (score -1):

To fix the issue you will need to add a ServerName directive to your Apache configuration.  If you have already added ServerName then check the ServerName.

Open apache2.conf file.
sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

Add the following line to the end of the file:
ServerName 127.0.0.1

Once you have added the ServerName directive to your configuration, run apachectl to test that the configuration is valid.

sudo apachectl configtest

A successful apachectl configtest invocation should result in output like this:

Output
Syntax OK

Comment: The notice about the server name is pretty common and does not affect Apaches ability to start. It's not relevant to the problem.